# Problems with encoding in ANTBuild

Tags: encoding, ant

I have a problem with my file after compiling with ANT Builder.

```
 <target name = "Compile">
<javac encoding="UTF-8" srcdir="src" destdir="web\WEB-INF\classes" failonerror="true" fork="true">
  <classpath refid="common_library">

  </classpath>
</javac>
```

In Servlet

```
resp.getWriter().write("кириллица");
```

but after compiling in byte code:

```
var2.getWriter().write("РєРёСЂРёР»Р»РёС†Р°");
```

and in web page Apache TomCat:

```
РєРёСЂРёР»Р»РёС†Р°
```

whats problem there? Can you help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Validate that the source file encoding is really UTF-8 and it is not ISO-8859-1 or something else